# Python virtualenv Can't set up! MAC OS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Hello everyone i'm trying to set up virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on MAC OS and made huge research  tried everything what i can. DOESN't Work.

I had python 2.7, i installed python 3.7 using regular installer from the python website.
Installed everything what i need but getting error:

> /usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
>   virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization
>   hooks.
>
> If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
>   check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set
>   properly.

Here is my ~/.bashrc :

> export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/code
>   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python export
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv export
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
>
> source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Here is where my python3 is installed

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3

So in the end i did create one using

> virtualenv -p python3 "desired-path"

but when i tried to set up everything with Django nothing is working bc of problem above. Any help please!!

Answer (score 0):

About 6 hours and i have a way to solve it so if anyone has the same problem just go ahead and change your ~/.bashrc (by typing in Terminal nano ~/.bashrc) to:

> export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/code
>
> export
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenv
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages' source
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 0):

See this [great explanation](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac), section "What we should do"